# Scope issues canvas createjs

Tags: javascript, createjs

Hi I'm having trouble accessing vars in createjs

I'll give a simplified version of what's happening if you want the complete script let me know.

```
var exportRoot, stage, etc//shouldn't these be global?

init(){
 handleLoadComplete()
}
handleLoadComplete(){
myFucntionCall()
console.log(exportRoot); //works fine
}

console.log(exportRoot); //doesn't work

myFucntionCall(){
 console.log(exportRoot); //works
}
```

Comment: I think it will help if you create actual smallest possible valid javascript (for example, with http://jsfiddle.net/), which reproduces your problem. Code above is not valid js, so hard to comment on what exactly is going on.

Comment: I agree with @sbat, but based on what you have supplied, it sounds like you're probably running into a race condition where you are logging exportRoot before it is initialized.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you time,
in the end I just put all functions into the handleLoadComplete function that's called from the init function, I'll have to investigate properly another time, but yes Andrew that sounds like that might be it.
Thanks again